# virtual server to run asp.net project without visual studio

Tags: asp.net, virtual

i make a web application in asp.net and this application will run on multiple computers on small network without server client ... and i need to run it without using visual studio

because the user is not asp expert ... so how to do that ??

is there is a way to make a virtual server or to run localhost ??

my web application within this path :

```
C:\Users\Samy\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Redcrescent\PrecompiledWeb\Redcrescent
```

login.aspx the firstpage

Comment: You can install IIS on a computer. Then deploy your site to that.

Comment: you will not need visual studio on your servers, you will however need the appropriate .net framework installed

Answer (score 3):

You can host the web application on your local machine.. yes, you will need to set up IIS and configure it to do so. Then you would publish the web application to IIS.

You can google how to set up IIS on Windows 7 or whatever operating system you have.

This [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762.aspx) will help as well.

Comment: i need without windows server ... its small network work group not server client

Comment: That's correct. If you have Windows 7 installed on your computer, you can install IIS (Internet Information Services) onto your computer. This is what will give you intranet access to the web application. You will have to configure a url so when the user types it in, it's redirected to your web application. Windows Server is not needed, but Windows Server can also have IIS installed on it. IIS is an option feature to install on Windows 7 pro, ultimate, and enterprise and I believe it's optional for Windows 8 all versions. > http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/

Comment: i did activate the iis but how to open my web application in it ?

Comment: You must publish it to the IIS. You can find all this information on-line. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx ... this will show you how to publish your website or webapp to IIS.

Comment: i publish the website and configure iis on windows 7 and add the website in iis manage successfully but i don't know how to run the website yet

Comment: Type the URL you set up into the browser.... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32210/Deployment-of-a-Website-on-IIS